# how to return multiple values of struct from get function in c++?

Tags: c++

I have made a struct data member in my class. Now, I want to return values of that struct using a get function, but it is generating errors. I am not sure what the datatype of the `getcenter()` function should be, and what the body should be.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class circle
{
    private:
        struct center
        { 
            int xcord;
            int ycord;
        };
        center cordinate;
        float radius;
    public:
        circle()//:circle(0,0,0)
        {
            cordinate.xcord=0;
            cordinate.ycord=0;
            radius=0;
        };

        circle(int x, int y, float r) : cordinate{x,y}, radius(r)
        {};

        center getcenter()  
        {
            return cordinate{xcord,ycord};
        }

        float getradius()
        {
            return radius;
        }

        void setcenter(int xaxis, int yaxis)
        {
            cordinate.xcord=xaxis;
            cordinate.ycord=yaxis;
        }

        void setradius(float rad)
        {
            radius=rad;
        }

        void showdata()
        {
            cout<<"Center(x,y) = ("<<cordinate.xcord<<","<<cordinate.ycord<<")"<<endl;
            cout<<"Radius = "<<radius<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    circle c1;
    c1.setcenter(3,4);
    c1.setradius(5.4);
    cout<<c1.getcenter()<<endl;
    cout<<c1.getradius()<<endl;
}
```

How can I write the `getcenter()` function?

It is giving me these errors:

```
Error   C2065   'xcord': undeclared identifier

Error   C2065   'ycord': undeclared identifier

Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'circle::center' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code? If it doesn't compile, then show the error messages.

Comment: *but it is generating error* What error? Please post it in the question.

Comment: Logically, your `struct` looks like it should be named `coordinate`, not `center`, and `center` should be `coordinate`. In other words, a circle's center is an instance of a coordinate.

Comment: `return cordinate{xcord,ycord;};` -- Explain what you are trying to accomplish with this line of code.

Comment: Since `struct center` is declared as `private` within your class, I don't think anything outside the class can make reference to it.

Comment: `return cordinate{xcord,ycord};` should be `return cordinate;`.   The errors about no operator found are because YOU need to declare an `operator<<()`that can output a `center` - it doesn't happen by magic.   Voting to close as a typo.  (also because it is more than one question in one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the corrected code which compiles. You had many errors coming from your `<<` operator which was not implemented for the `circle` class. 
You can either write a `toString()` method (which could print in a nice way what a circle is) or override the `<<` operator for the `circle` class.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class circle
{
    private:
        struct center
        { 
            int xcord;
            int ycord;
        };
        center cordinate;
        float radius;
    public:
        circle()
        {
            cordinate.xcord=0;
            cordinate.ycord=0;
            radius=0;
        };

        circle(int x, int y, float r){
            center c;
            c.xcord = x;
            c.ycord = y;
            this->cordinate = c;
            this->radius = r;
        }

        center getcenter()  
        {
            return cordinate;
        }

        float getradius()
        {
            return radius;
        }

        void setcenter(int xaxis, int yaxis)
        {
            cordinate.xcord=xaxis;
            cordinate.ycord=yaxis;
        }

        void setradius(float rad)
        {
            radius=rad;
        }

        void showdata()
        {
            cout<<"Center(x,y) = ("<<cordinate.xcord<<","<<cordinate.ycord<<")"<<endl;
            cout<<"Radius = "<<radius<<endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    circle c1;
    c1.setcenter(3,4);
    c1.setradius(5.4);
    cout<< "Coordinates: " << c1.getcenter().xcord << "\t" << c1.getcenter().ycord <<endl;
    cout<<c1.getradius()<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just

```
    center getcenter()  
    {
        return cordinate;
    }
```

`cordinate` holds the value you want to return, so just return it, no different from any other variable.

Although even better would be

```
    center getcenter() const
    {
        return cordinate;
    }
```

If a method does not modify an object it should be declared `const`.

BTW your naming seems all wrong. Surely the struct should be called `coordinate`, and the variable should be called `center`, not the other way around.

Comment: But you aren't addressing the errors in `main` - that there is no defined `operator <<` for the `center` structure.

Answer (score 1):

```
return cordinate{xcord,ycord;};
```

Should simply be:

```
return coordinate;
```

On top of that, when you fix that issue, you have several other errors. You can't use `operator<<` with a `center` object, until you've declared one yourself. Example:

```
struct center
{ 
    int xcord;
    int ycord;

    friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &os, const center &c ) {
        os << c.xcord << ' ' << c.ycord;
        return os;
    }
};
```

Secondly, your `center` struct is private, which it probably should not be (although, this last one doesn't actually cause an error).